# Ajax: div wouldn't get updated

Tags: jquery, ajax

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the following code? It always updates to a new page, instead of the "content" div. Thanks.

```
This is a test:<br />
   <a href="/form" onclick="return updateContent()">Click me</a>
     <div id="content">
       Update here.
   </div>

<script>
function updateContent() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(data) {
      $('#content').html(data);
    };
 });
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liang Tang. You have syntax error in your javascript code here:

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#content').html(data);
};
```

there is no need `;` after `}`. Anyways, this is the correct answer. Also don't use internal events like onclick in your HTML markup. Let's javascript/jquery handle them for you.

```
This is a test:<br />
<a href="form.html" id="link">Click me</a>
<div id="content">
Update here.
</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    $('#link').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            success: function(data) {
              $('#content').html(data);
            }
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

**Explanation**
1. I give your link an specific ID. So I can access it in jquery code.
2. In the `click` event of link, I cancel the link behaviour (with `e.preventDefault()`)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, you might as well use it properly. Your link is doing what links are meant to do since you have nothing that cancels the default behavior of the link.

Change:

```
<a href="/form" onclick="return updateContent()">Click me</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/form">Click me</a>
```

And change your jQuery to:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        };
    });
});​
```

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks a lot. But I do have one more question: What if I decide to use 'POST' method? I changed 'GET' into 'POST', the script didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead writing `<a href="/form" onclick="return updateContent()">Click me</a>`, write the following.
`<span style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="return updateContent()">Click me</span>`

The above will work.